# Inserting hindi text in between English paragraphs

Tags: xetex

I want to write some Hindi text along with English using LaTeX for eg: k=क, bollywood or (बॉलीवुड). I have used the below in the preamble but I'm getting the error command:

> \G already defined.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{mangal.ttf}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Script=Roman,Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043). I've put your quote in a quote block, and the code in a code block. Click on edit to see how to do these using the keyboard, but also note in the editor that there is a code tool marked with `{}`, and a similar quote tool.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Devanagari MT}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
bollywood or \foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{बॉलीवुड}
\end{document}
```

I've changed the Devanagari font to one that I have on my machine:

[image]

For longer parts in Sanskrit there's also the `otherlanguage*` environment. For entire paragraphs you can use the `sanskrit` environment, see the documentation of Polyglossia.

There's no need, in general, to load `xltxtra`.

Comment: thanks.its working. i tried it with my main document but due to package conflicts of amssymb and amsmth, it was giving errors. the sequence mentioned below solved all the problem.                                       {\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Mangal}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}}

Comment: If you're using Hindi you should set the main language to `hindi` not `sanskrit`, since (at least) the hyphenation patterns are different. (I don't know about other things.)