# How can I make Hindi pdf document in Latex without transliteration?

Tags: fonts, languages

I want to write a letter in Hindi. I want to use LaTeX to create the PDF document in Hindi. I don't want to have transliteration from English to Hindi.  How can I do this?

Comment: Other than the specific language (Bengali vs Hindi) the following question is an exact duplicate: [How to write Bengali in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99606) The simple answer is to use XeLaTeX and the `polyglossia` package.

Comment: Hi Alan,
Do you know about any good source for ttf/otf fiile for hindi fonts. I have googled fot it and most of the files create some issue - some characters don't get displayed properly.

Comment: I don't know much about Hindi fonts, but the SIL fonts are of good quality usually: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=annapurnasil

Comment: Hi Alan, I am using the SIL font now. Still I am facing issue with display. The words are not getting displayed properly in the pdf even though they are getting displayed correctly in source file. And when I tried to copy words from the pdf file and paste them, they are pasted as wha
t they should be (as they are in the source file) and not identical to pdf display

Comment: I have created the question at the following 

[link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184214/hindi-words-not-displayed-properly-in-pdf-generated-by-xelatex)

for it.

Answer (score 5):

Use the polyglossia package. Type in Hindi words using input systems like that from Google (http://www.google.co.in/inputtools/). There is no transliteration in the LaTeX source itself. Compile with XeLaTeX.

Sample:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Nakula}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{Nakula}

\begin{document}
Bollywood बॉलीवुड 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried whatever you mentioned. Still I am facing issue with display. The words are not getting displayed properly in the pdf even though they are getting displayed correctly in source file. And when I tried to copy words from the pdf file and paste them, they are pasted as what they should be (as they are in the source file) and not identical to pdf display.

Comment: I have created a new question at the following

[link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184214/hindi-words-not-displayed-properly-in-pdf-generated-by-xelatex)

for it.

Comment: With "Nakula" font, I am able to get the output fine. It can be downloaded from http://bombay.indology.info/software/fonts/devanagari/

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are using the De­vana­gari script.

Below are some links to LaTeX's official documentation for Hindi. Unfortunately, much of the work done is LaTeX does involve transliteration:

[Here](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb23-1/trehan.pdf) is a general overview geared towards people just learning how to use Hindi for LaTeX.

Here is a link to an offical package supporting the De­vana­gari script.

[Here](http://pravin.paratey.com/files/devanagari.pdf) is another link to the documentation for another package that supports  the Devanagari script. It should be noted that this package (or the documentation) has not been updated in over 20 years. [Here's](http://pravin.paratey.com/posts/using-devanagari-in-latex) a tutorial in utilizing this same package.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45135/inserting-hindi-text-in-between-english-paragraphs) is a Tex.SE post that may help.

Comment: XeLaTeX allows one to use OpenType fonts with Devanagari scripts directly. Posting links to really outdated information isn't terribly helpful, I'm afraid.

Comment: I didn't know that! I will have to look at XeLaTeX again. Thanks!