# I want to write a Hindi couplet in .tex file?

Tags: languages, letters

जिन खोजा तिन पाइया, गहरे पानी पैठ,
मैं बपुरा बूडन डरा, रहा किनारे बैठ।

How can I write this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the polyglossia package (as they did it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183174)).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Nakula}

\begin{document}
जिन खोजा तिन पाइया, गहरे पानी पैठ, मैं बपुरा बूडन डरा, रहा किनारे बैठ।
\end{document}
```